# I have a column "POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT" WHICH IS IN VARCHAR DATATYPE AND IT HOLDS THE DOLLAR VALUE

Tags: sql-server-2008

Now i want to add a thousand separator to that column. 
but when i add this query to that column

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT),1), '.00','') from table
```

i am getting this error

> cannot convert a char value to money.

Please help

Comment: Is it too late to fix the column type?

Comment: No..but what should datatype should be givne

Comment: How about [MONEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql)? In your code it's clear that you're already aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

If the $ is after the value, like 100$ then below query will help in converting.

```
    create table #tmp (POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT varchar(10))
insert into #tmp values ('$100'),('-$150')
select REPLACE(CONVERT(MONEY,RIGHT(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT,LEN(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT)-1)), '.00','')
FROM #tmp
WHERE LEN(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT)=LEN(REPLACE(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT,'-',''))
UNION ALL
select REPLACE(CONVERT(MONEY,RIGHT(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT,LEN(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT)-1)), '.00','')
FROM #tmp
WHERE LEN(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT)!=LEN(REPLACE(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT,'-',''))
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **Always use appropriate types to store your values!**

Secondly: Never use `(n)char` (same with `(n)varchar`) without a size! ([Aaron Bertrand: Bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length))

Third: Never store information, which is just a formatting issue together with the value (the dollar symbol).

Now check this

```
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,'$1234.56') --This works. The leading "$" is ignored.
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,'1234.56$') --Breaks with your error message
```

As a repair fix you can use replace to get rid of the symbol:

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,REPLACE(POLICY_RATE_AMOUNT,'$','')),1), '.00','') from xyz
```